# Jews were on 49th level of Tumah. Says who?

Tags: sources-mekorot, provenance, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, yetziat-mitzrayim, agada-stories-legends

There is a well known idea that when the Jews left Egypt during the Exodus, they were on the "forty-ninth level of *tumah*". Many explanations are given for this and it is expounded upon at length by a number of great commentators and other writers.

However, whenever I've seen this concept brought up, it is always with a vague reference or none at all. I've seen it introduced with "...ידוע הוא" or "...אמרו חכמינו ז"ל" or "...נכתב בספרים הקדושים" or the like, without any direct quote as to where this comes from. A search on Bar Ilan doesn't find anything earlier than around the 17th century that talks about this idea; certainly not any midrashic sources.

Where does this concept come from? I'm looking for its earliest source, preferably a midrashic or Talmudic one.

Comment: Rabbi Akiva Tatz has a beautiful explanation here: https://torahdownloads.com/shiur-15839.html

Comment: What sources have you seen that discuss this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Googled it and came up with [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32914&pgnum=308) page (see top left). It says to look at [Zohar Chadash Yisro 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24807&pgnum=88).

In the Zohar, it is referred to as `ארבעים ותשע חילי דמסאבותא`

Comment: here is a link to a more readable version: http://www.dailyzohar.co.il/index2.php?id=175&lang=HEB

Comment: @Menachem, ba, What is the literally meaning of the word "דמסאבותא" where does it come from?

Comment: @Yehoshua: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/ppages/JastrowP206428.gif

Comment: Does it say that the Jews in Egypt were on this level? Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 7):

[image]
Here is a picture of the Zohar with the perush masok midvash on bottom. It is zohar charash yisro on daf lamed tes amud aleph in the original Zohar print.

Comment: Thank you. We hope you stick around and continue to contribute to Mi Yodeya.